# Given these 3  considerations, is HTML5 suitable for this?

Tags: jquery, html

I`m making an educational game that has 16 very short sound files. User clicks a start button, one sound file is randomly chosen  from an array and the sound file is played. After that, other stuff happens...

Considerations.

1. I'm thinking that HTML5 might be suitable because I could assign a different id to each sound file, making it easier to randomly choose one using javascript from an array of all 16 files...
2. I'm assuming there's a way to use a javascript call back to make the audio file to play after it is randomly chosen. Ideally, I don't want the user to have to click  a separate "play" button
3. On the other hand, it's a game for students studying English as a second language, and a lot of people in Asia don't use the latest browsers, so HTML5 support isn't guaranteed.

So, Is HTML5 suitable to store the files in the browswer and accomplish these objectives?

Comment: HTML5 isn't as important as the browser that you're going to be using to view this, if you have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could go directly for HTML5 `<audio>` in this case, the support for it isn't very wide yet.

And, as Radu says, Asian countries are still big on older browsers.

I would recommend using [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to accomplish what you're doing. It provides an easy to use API for controlling audio from JavaScript, and it supports different ways of playing back the audio so you can better guarantee it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those times when you should go with flash. Asia is the greatest IE6 user and you're definitely not getting HTML5 `<audio>` goodness out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you're talking about requires HTML5. It's all standard stuff where you store the file location of the 16 sound files in an array, select a random index of the array and play that sound when the play button is clicked.

Comment: thanks, if you didn`t use html5 to put the sound files in the browser, where would they be stored, and what sound player could you use to access them randomly?  Do you have any advice on that?